# Getting ConcurrentModificationException while modifying a HashMap in a thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi I am running a thread service, the job of this thread is to check the age of a list items in a  `HashMap`. When an item is older than say 5 seconds, I will have to delete the item from the `HashMap`. The below is the simplified code. But when the code attempts to delete the item from the HashMap, I get a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

I am populating the `HashMap` in the `main()` method in the original program. 
Can somebody please help me out with this ? 
PS: The `deleteFromTrackList()` is being called by different clients across a network through RMI.

```
import java.util.*;

public class NotifierThread extends Thread {

    private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList> NotificationTrackList = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList>();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) { // this process should run continuously
            checkNotifierList(getNotificationTrackList());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public HashMap<Integer, ArrayList> getNotificationTrackList() {
        return NotificationTrackList;
    }

    public void deleteFromTrackList(Integer messageID) {
        NotificationTrackList.remove(messageID);
    }

    public synchronized void checkNotifierList(HashMap list) {

        Set entries = list.entrySet();

        for (Iterator iterator = entries.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList> entry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next(); 

            ArrayList messageInfo = entry.getValue();
            Integer messageID = entry.getKey();

            messageInfo = new ArrayList((ArrayList) list.get(messageID));
            Long curTime = new Date().getTime();
            Long refTime = (Long) messageInfo.get(1);
            Long timeDiff = curTime - refTime;

            if (timeDiff > 5000) {
                // delete the entry if its older than 5 milliseconds and update
                // internal entry list
                deleteFromTrackList(messageID);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NotifierThread().start();
    }
}
```

This is the stacktrace I am getting at the console

```
Exception in thread "tracker" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at NotifierThread.checkNotifierList(NotifierThread.java:32)
    at NotifierThread.run(NotifierThread.java:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers guys... I have found the solution for my question, instead of using `HashMap`, I am using `ConcurrentHashMap`. This solved my problem. Thanks again !

Answer (score 4):

The only way to remove an entry from a map while iterating over it is to remove it using the iterator. Use

```
iterator.remove();
```

instead of

```
deleteFromTrackList(messageID);
```

Note that the same applies to all the collections (List, Set, etc.)

Also, note that your design is not thread-safe, because you let other threads access the map in an unsynchronized way.

Comment: I tried `iterator.remove();` But I need to remove the item outside of the loop, as the `deleteFromTrackList(messageID);` is being called by different clients across network through RMI.

Comment: The fact that you need to have a separate method to enable other clients to remove a message ID doesn't prevent you to use iterator.remove when you remove it while iterating. You should just make sure that no other thread calls deleteFromTrackList while you're iterating over the list. Don't let the map escape your class, and synchronize every access to the map.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. You cannot modify a Map while iterating over it without using the iterator directly. There are a couple main options.

1. Create a List of elements that should be removed. Add each expired element to the List in the loop. After the loop, remove the elements in the List from the Map.
2. Use Guava's filter capability.
   [Maps.filterEntries](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#filterEntries%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) This creates a new Map however which may not work for what you are trying to do.

Since you have a multi-threaded system. You may want to consider immutability as your friend. Rather than blocking threads over your entire check for stale loop, you could use an [ImmutableMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) which would be more thread-safe with better performance.

Comment: I have to modify the list before completion of the loop. Is there any way to do this ? Meanwhile I will check the Guava's filter capability. Thanks.

Comment: Using the Iterator.remove method. Are you sure that you need to remove from within the loop. Depending on your synchronization, no other thread will have access to the map which you are checking it so I would think I would not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't complectly synchronized. Try to change

```
public void deleteFromTrackList(Integer messageID) {
```

to

```
public synchronized void deleteFromTrackList(Integer messageID) {
```

Comment: This is probably a good thing to fix, but it would not fix the `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: And the method getNotificationTrackList() would also have to be removed (or modified to be synchronized and return a copy of the map) to make it thread-safe

Answer (score 0):

In reality you do not even need concurrent access to an hash map to get a concurrency exception.
In fact, a single thread is quite enough.

For example,
You may create a loop based on the hash map map.keySet().iterator(),
And, while you are within this loop, your (single) thread decides to remove an element from the hash map. (Not a good idea while the iterator is open.)
In the next request to the iterator().next() you will get your concurrency exception.

So careful with that.